# Realtime updated field in google maps marker label

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps

i was wondering if there is a way to update in realtime a field of a google maps marker label (i.e. print in realtime the output value of a remote sensor which is represented as a marker in a google map).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google map does not allow us to place markers dynamically.
Instead use mapbox and leaflet for the purpose.
Leaflet allows you to place marker dynamically and trace the route remotely via gps in the form of polygon.